# Infinite geometric series and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been given the infinite geometric series-:
$$
2-\frac 4x + \frac8{x^2}
-\frac{16}{x^3}+\dots
(x\neq 0)$$
I am asked to

1. Find the convergence area to the sequence
2. Find the sum $S(x)$ and the domain

I'm completely stuck as to how I should proceed!

When I use $X$ values greater than $0$ and less than $1$ it seems as though the series alternates between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$  as I approach infinity...

With $X$ values less than $0$ it seems to approach $+ \infty$?

I have no idea, could some kind soul shine a light?

Comment: What do you know about infinite geometric series in general?  When do they converge?

Comment: First step: Find the $n^\textrm{th}$ term of the series, as a function of $n$.

Comment: I believe that they converge when the quotient is between -1 and 1. But it seems like if X is any value between -1 and 1 the series approaches infinity, either positive when X is less than 0 and alternating positive/negative when X is greater than 0?

Comment: Sorry vadim123 - how do I begin to do that? So sorry to be a pain but I really don't know much about this particular area :C

Answer (score 1):

The series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, for  $a_n=2(\frac{-2}{x})^n$.

A good first step is to compute $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and simplify.  If this is constant, you have a geometric series you can sum with the formula.  If not, you can apply the ratio test.

Comment: Much appreciated! I will attempt to follow your advice - in the morning, its late and my brain has gone to bed and I cannot comprehend;D  Again, many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Ok, back to it! Once again, sorry to be a pain, currently I have no helpful literature or explanations as to how to tackle this - i'm studying in a foreign language and I cannot understand my textbook at all.  Have I misunderstood something crucial - I believed that the X valus could only be between -1 and 1? If X is allowed to be any value this would change everything?

Comment: Hi vadim123 - well it seems like any X value greater than but not equal to 2 or less than -2 will converge since the common ratio is less than 1 - am I on the right track here?

Comment: That is correct, you need $|\frac{-2}{x}|<1$, which rearranges to $|x|>2$.

Answer (score -1):

The sum 
$S(x) = 2(1+2/x)^{-1}$

Comment: Appreciate the help! Thank you! Am waiting nervously - were the previous statements incorrect?

Comment: About the interval of convergence, nope sorry. Check against a few values and it didn't work.

Comment: Does this mean that the series only diverges?

Comment: No, there is an interval, which you'll have to work out, in which the infinite sum converges to that of the above post.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try to do as you suggest :D